# iPhone App crash log - How to get class name and method name in crash log?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, crash-reports, plcrashreporter

I am using the [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/) to get crash log of my application, I am getting below information from crash log

```
<CrashReportInterface><CrashReport><applicationname>Basic</applicationname><bundleidentifier>com.iMobDev.weed</bundleidentifier><systemversion>6.0</systemversion><platform>x86_64</platform><senderversion>1.0</senderversion><version>1.0</version><userid></userid><contact></contact><description><![CDATA[]]></description><log><![CDATA[Incident Identifier: [TODO]
CrashReporter Key:   [TODO]
Process:         Basic [714]
Path:            /Users/bhavinparmar/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/068F158F-CE56-46DD-B5D7-F93FD8FFB199/Basic.app/Basic
Identifier:      com.iMobDev.weed
Version:         1.0
Code Type:       X86
Parent Process:  debugserver [716]

Date/Time:       2012-12-20 14:12:04 +0000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 6.0
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0xffffffff9ca719c6
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x9ca719c6 0x9ca59000 + 100806
1   libsystem_sim_c.dylib               0x018fd57b 0x18b6000 + 292219
2   libc++abi.dylib                     0x01a7df7b 0x1a7b000 + 12155
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x01a7ba25 0x1a7b000 + 2597
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0170a0c1 0x1704000 + 24769
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x01a7ba65 0x1a7b000 + 2661
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x01a7bacd 0x1a7b000 + 2765
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x01a7cbc2 0x1a7b000 + 7106
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01709f89 0x1704000 + 24457
9   CoreFoundation                      0x01bb60b4 0x1b88000 + 188596
10  Basic                               0x00023fc1 0x1000 + 143297
11  UIKit                               0x00929817 0x83d000 + 968727
12  UIKit                               0x00929882 0x83d000 + 968834
13  UIKit                               0x00929b2a 0x83d000 + 969514
14  UIKit                               0x00940ef5 0x83d000 + 1064693
15  UIKit                               0x00940fdb 0x83d000 + 1064923
16  UIKit                               0x00941286 0x83d000 + 1065606
17  UIKit                               0x00941381 0x83d000 + 1065857
18  UIKit                               0x00941eab 0x83d000 + 1068715
19  UIKit                               0x00941fc9 0x83d000 + 1069001
20  UIKit                               0x00942055 0x83d000 + 1069141
21  UIKit                               0x00a473ab 0x83d000 + 2139051
22  UIKit                               0x0089892d 0x83d000 + 375085
23  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0171d6b0 0x1704000 + 104112
24  QuartzCore                          0x02d6ffc0 0x2c74000 + 1032128
25  QuartzCore                          0x02d6433c 0x2c74000 + 983868
26  QuartzCore                          0x02d64150 0x2c74000 + 983376
27  QuartzCore                          0x02ce20bc 0x2c74000 + 450748
28  QuartzCore                          0x02ce3227 0x2c74000 + 455207
29  QuartzCore                          0x02d85b50 0x2c74000 + 1121104
30  UIKit                               0x008469ff 0x83d000 + 39423
31  UIKit                               0x008474e1 0x83d000 + 42209
32  UIKit                               0x00858315 0x83d000 + 111381
33  UIKit                               0x0085924b 0x83d000 + 115275
34  UIKit                               0x0084acf8 0x83d000 + 56568
35  GraphicsServices                    0x0229ddf9 0x2294000 + 40441
36  GraphicsServices                    0x0229dad0 0x2294000 + 39632
37  CoreFoundation                      0x01b89bf5 0x1b88000 + 7157
38  CoreFoundation                      0x01b89962 0x1b88000 + 6498
39  CoreFoundation                      0x01bbabb6 0x1b88000 + 207798
40  CoreFoundation                      0x01bb9f44 0x1b88000 + 204612
41  CoreFoundation                      0x01bb9e1b 0x1b88000 + 204315
42  UIKit                               0x008467da 0x83d000 + 38874
43  UIKit                               0x0084865c 0x83d000 + 46684
44  Basic                               0x0000278d 0x1000 + 6029
45  Basic                               0x000026c5 0x1000 + 5829

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x9ca7202e 0x9ca59000 + 102446
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9c8f56fe 0x9c895000 + 395006

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x9ca72926 0x9ca59000 + 104742
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x018818cc 0x187b000 + 26828

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x9ca7202e 0x9ca59000 + 102446
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9c8f56fe 0x9c895000 + 395006

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x9ca6fc22 0x9ca59000 + 93218
1   CoreFoundation                      0x01bb5a49 0x1b88000 + 186953
2   CoreFoundation                      0x01bba8d4 0x1b88000 + 207060
3   CoreFoundation                      0x01bb9f44 0x1b88000 + 204612
4   CoreFoundation                      0x01bb9e1b 0x1b88000 + 204315
5   WebCore                             0x03e8d310 0x3184000 + 13669136
6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9c8f1ed9 0x9c895000 + 380633
7   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9c8f56de 0x9c895000 + 394974

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State:
   eax: 0x00000000    edx:  0x9ca719c6    ecx:  0xbfffbfdc    ebx:  0x0a37a000 
   ebp: 0xbfffbff8    esi:  0x00000006    edi:  0xad2822c0    esp:  0xbfffbfdc 
   eip: 0x9ca719c6 eflags:  0x00000246 trapno:  0x00000084     cs:  0x0000000b 
    ds: 0x00000023     es:  0x00000023     fs:  0x00000000     gs:  0x0000000f 


Binary Images:
r/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x2c74000 - 0x2dc9000  QuartzCore armv6 <e4a8af9f2f2a3b05bf64dc8282af2eee> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x2e4a000 - 0x2e9c000  AppSupport armv6 <b4790eafc2ea3f00ae35a98f5869ec11> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x2ecb000 - 0x2f7a000  CoreText armv6 <9c4b4e7a1ba7346fa11c8d3050d5dcb9> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x2fc2000 - 0x30de000  WebKit armv6 <b364c41a756835ae9818b7eb735c0b65> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3184000 - 0x45b8000  WebCore armv6 <d33362b423c93f73849e5b5689cf276d> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x4d98000 - 0x4e41000  ProofReader armv6 <dba9674afeec3d21a4795407e72bbc10> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x4e57000 - 0x4e60000  libAccessibility.dylib armv6 <e8ea896f17ac3df9afa6ff5d00877622> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x4e6c000 - 0x4e6d000  Accelerate armv6 <ce335a8e605f30639efdac17af266960> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x4e70000 - 0x4ea8000  PrintKit armv6 <035cd3b76d303575a51a4b938499e55e> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x4ebe000 - 0x4f22000  libc++.1.dylib armv6 <9e0b682e27de36c6803704a8457c4d97> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x4f70000 - 0x4f7d000  OpenGLES armv6 <f39053050f283db39f52156af69132d5> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x4f86000 - 0x4f8d000  libGFXShared.dylib armv6 <8c38c13795383c9ba6b461375d32312c> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x4f92000 - 0x4fd3000  libGLImage.dylib armv6 <6f1e0b08050f31cdac21c754463499f1> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x4fda000 - 0x4fdd000  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv6 <677b62949b6d315d857b5f621f5ddcba> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x4fe1000 - 0x4fea000  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv6 <ccd3c931f2783d28953cf6ee87ce2af1> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x4ff1000 - 0x5806000  libLLVMContainer.dylib armv6 <94738cccc81c3d2a8792cf4b7d4083d8> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libLLVMContainer.dylib
0x5b45000 - 0x5b9a000  CoreMedia armv6 <a7bb17673a8b307fa9bd7167a2c1aa14> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x5bcb000 - 0x5c4a000  CoreAudio armv6 <572522cb240e34b3914e18edf9a6b87a> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x5c81000 - 0x5c8f000  AssetsLibraryServices armv6 <953cf80db1de35e5a245473e28c2560c> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x5c9b000 - 0x5c9e000  TCC armv6 <023d22dfa37b3f5e85f6396bccc7f6d4> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x5ca2000 - 0x5e3a000  vImage armv6 <b0ef7abdf20e3616b8b2bab707710833> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x5e59000 - 0x5e5a000  vecLib armv6 <9a41b0b7bbe9391897e28bee279587b8> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x5e5d000 - 0x5ecb000  libvDSP.dylib armv6 <9b33c01f7de43623bdec7b4dd52581d0> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x5ed4000 - 0x62a6000  libLAPACK.dylib armv6 <0c339eb79a1f3f6db7cfab21606fcfc7> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x62d1000 - 0x6415000  libBLAS.dylib armv6 <88cfed9fd0723bde802308af901c91e7> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x6433000 - 0x64a2000  libvMisc.dylib armv6 <b95307f9a4383e48afd9b392adb0b8cf> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x64a9000 - 0x655a000  CoreTelephony armv6 <720a6454935635dea277edc8aafd21ae> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x65a5000 - 0x6600000  IMFoundation armv6 <2b25c545f243399eb0ec08dcfd4fbe5a> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x662a000 - 0x662c000  DataMigration armv6 <396934af265b39c78eca4faca29cb287> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x6630000 - 0x6634000  MobileInstallation armv6 <85dc2b1385ec31db977154e80e911562> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x6639000 - 0x663e000  MobileSystemServices armv6 <f5f1e086f3343700a427e5c0b8f9a789> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x6643000 - 0x667c000  Bom armv6 <43d5f33d0e1f32c6aa1304da48a641d2> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x668a000 - 0x6697000  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv6 <e1b2bafe50a43e9289deaec39ac82cb9> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x669b000 - 0x66a3000  CommonUtilities armv6 <33c9d324c7933391a19ad84c1936c475> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x66aa000 - 0x66db000  libtidy.A.dylib armv6 <81a8363c8ad63dad8a1b58a00b2497fd> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x66e7000 - 0x6a10000  JavaScriptCore armv6 <24ae2dfe548f394294937fc69a0b9227> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x6aaf000 - 0x6ed1000  FaceCoreLight armv6 <b7739ff40bdb3d89bc476c7edebd86cc> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x70e1000 - 0x710e000  libxslt.1.dylib armv6 <20e7d089e224368f8ce64c1bc37d5414> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x7119000 - 0x720d000  libiconv.2.dylib armv6 <4d8fd7b10fbf325c9308fe20a1825d66> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x7219000 - 0x721a000  libresolv.dylib armv6 <fdc9e86e2d833459bbb2d9118c0a7527> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libresolv.dylib
0x721e000 - 0x7223000  AggregateDictionary armv6 <035e788a885236a8a8a0aae57f2a7f27> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x9433c000 - 0x9435a000  libresolv.9.dylib armv6 <2870320a28da3b449d82d56e0036f6bb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x7228000 - 0x7540000  AudioToolbox armv6 <95ee99005f803990820bffe259e6bc04> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x75fc000 - 0x7602000  FTClientServices armv6 <184c4501dd0d3a12b2560294103d797c> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x7607000 - 0x7706000  AddressBookUI armv6 <14c915b288eb33c7b985ea17484370a7> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x779b000 - 0x788d000  Message armv6 <708a34f84e623c8bb83c7fdeeceafa92> loper/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x7a40000 - 0x7b4f000  EventKit armv6 <66fe344b12af3494910afcb531914d56> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x7bd1000 - 0x7bdf000  MailServices armv6 <7455dac19d8331588dbcf3f9010ac97f> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x7bec000 - 0x7c37000  MIME armv6 <fb9a2e54e0473813b2eb539904ec4ba2> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x7c5e000 - 0x7c8f000  Celestial armv6 <f3ada760f73b3783a40c4541cc0128d3> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x7cbb000 - 0x7cd4000  DataAccessExpress armv6 <efb3fcc1129e3d14814fce123bc91bd4> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x7ce8000 - 0x7d4d000  QuickLook armv6 <7d4dfac8cc8831a3b294cf43c37c2cf0> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x7d89000 - 0x7d8c000  MessageSupport armv6 <47f0fc1d441934359aabdcc1f98a9426> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessageSupport.framework/MessageSupport
0x7d91000 - 0x7ebb000  AVFoundation armv6 <20543bfb45483dfbb1d1c218853ce929> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x7f7c000 - 0x8011000  IMCore armv6 <ba1dee76d4cd31808aeb380a18cc405c> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x8036000 - 0x803f000  Marco armv6 <373df9ef364433cf9b6aa0659dbfc8ce> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x8044000 - 0x8081000  FTServices armv6 <2a91a60968b7320a86dbd3ef1ce1ead6> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x8097000 - 0x810b000  ManagedConfiguration armv6 <0eacf3d28a5f373288fc93877f67f73a> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x814e000 - 0x8166000  Accounts armv6 <26159e4e51553f7cb94622803df1fe2f> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x8177000 - 0x817a000  OAuth armv6 <30f6af9ed6463d2897451fbb67c87b2a> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x817e000 - 0x818e000  AccountSettings armv6 <b3942fc6bd8b31d480bd8cfa1a5d302a> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x8197000 - 0x81b8000  PersistentConnection armv6 <2f58ef514fed39ae8e89312ff4693d6d> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x81d1000 - 0x81d7000  CertUI armv6 <7d52e457f94c3fb99be24d6229d9208f> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x81de000 - 0x81e3000  ActorKit armv6 <ed34e294b7ec3b8bb6a980230f7e478e> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x81e8000 - 0x8216000  MobileSync armv6 <dcac2bfaed253ee29cc962d8889b3673> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x822b000 - 0x824e000  Notes armv6 <1aa11a94b3d43baf9e66d2232778f622> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x825c000 - 0x82c9000  CoreLocation armv6 <a523c8e1959336879d0a83f0b30558a3> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x82f9000 - 0x834c000  iCalendar armv6 <c5c31e6f74ce316e86573d2dfbe4e707> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x8375000 - 0x85c0000  CoreData armv6 <728437d5bf693166a1a0eca4420fcfa6> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x8681000 - 0x87cf000  GeoServices armv6 <0ca8c2435e1f392db56a1e37fc1a05a0> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x8874000 - 0x8880000  ProtocolBuffer armv6 <d6ca312b653f3cdeac074f6d9d4c2aa0> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x8889000 - 0x88a1000  MobileDeviceLink armv6 <dfa30d31e4e3362c97232b06a4a28d1b> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x88ac000 - 0x88d9000  AppleAccount armv6 <60ae3b5b8af33947b445e860a5f619eb> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x88f6000 - 0x8937000  ContentIndex armv6 <289e1c7f25c73a888de10a33a80ab13f> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x8952000 - 0x8966000  ApplePushService armv6 <6a5a069c5ff432efa1b90d43d1aafabe> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x8975000 - 0x8b80000  MediaToolbox armv6 <cb900c13c29d3a0596a3ffb603f79c4e> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x8c2c000 - 0x8de2000  MediaPlayer armv6 <e946f42f7a2f35399a732c3d1a637daf> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x8ef3000 - 0x8f41000  iTunesStore armv6 <5ec3bcb6be4a3c47bf8efb90264b61ca> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x8f74000 - 0x8f81000  IAP armv6 <c54a5e46b4d233a785841d00a17b1f64> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x8f8c000 - 0x9068000  MusicLibrary armv6 <dff42be5bc6e3c1f9babdcfc238db644> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x90cd000 - 0x9173000  StoreServices armv6 <4e8512b86fd83c4db96e4177dfadd594> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x91e2000 - 0x91ee000  MediaRemote armv6 <cec25c07b332345d92c11e2fdfcfe5ee> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x91f8000 - 0x922d000  HomeSharing armv6 <9ffbf87e9aa53e059f2e1b60a0e7a2be> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x924f000 - 0x92a0000  MediaControlSender armv6 <39bbf404941e3025acc5786d22e85279> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x92c0000 - 0x9366000  CoreMotion armv6 <1cc36264c5ef3deba0820a69ab601bd8> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0xa700000 - 0xa74b000  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv6 <4b3ffcd7dfb73542a6d46a4047b94d58> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0xa75e000 - 0xa787000  libRIP.A.dylib armv6 <752b122b8ec130af944b0c9e0a0ca550> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0xa4f6000 - 0xa4f9000  DebuggerIntrospectionSupport.dylib armv6 <809f222b8eaf30f585bd98e0c7689940> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerFoundation.ideplugin/Contents/Resources/DebuggerIntrospectionSupport.dylib
]]></log></CrashReport></CrashReportInterface>
```

Now i want Class name and function name in crash log, where application is crashing in source code, so i can get solution easily...........

Please help me,

Thanks in advance.....!

Answer (score 2):

You want to do "Symbolication".

See this [Apple Document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-ANALYZING_CRASH_REPORTS-SYMBOLICATION) regarding symbolication or search for other tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script I made to make symbolicating easier

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Drop crash..."
read s2
echo "Drop dSYM..."
read s3
export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer"
symbolicatecrash "$s2" "$s3" > "$s2.txt"
```

Just save this as SymbolicateCrashScript.sh and run chmod 755 on it from the terminal.

Also make sure your .app and .dsym from the build it crashed on are in the same folder before doing this.

Comment: XCode does it all for you if you use the tools!

Comment: It should work, but a lot of the time it doesn't.  Plus I find it easier to just keep a library of all my separate builds then just run this script and drop the crash when I need to.

Comment: If you use the XCode Organiser to create an Archive of your build, it does it all for you and all you have to do is give it the crash file